# How do I structure this nested for loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to use a nested for loop to print the values 192.168.42.0-255 and 192.168.43.0-255.

```
for i in range(42, 43):
    for y in range(0, 255):
        ip = "192.168." + str(i) + "." + str(y)
        print ip
```

All that is printing is the values 192.168.42.0-255. It doesn't seem to be changing to 192.168.43.

Comment: you can also use an iterable in the outer loop, e.g. `for i in (42, 43): ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`range(x,y)` does not include y.

```
>>> range(42,43)
[42]
```

Your code can be fixed by changing the first one to `range(42,44)` and the second one to `range(0,256)` (or just `range(256)`).

If you want to get rid of the nested loops altogether, you can use a generator expression:

```
for ip in ('192.168.{}.{}'.format(i,j) for i in (42,43) for j in range(256)):
    print(ip)
```

Comment: The last solution demonstrates the beauty of Python!

Answer (score 1):

`range(42,43)` gives only `[42]`. Change that to only `for i in (42,43):`.

And as @timgeb pointed out, your 2nd loop should be `range(0, 256)` or just `range(256)`; not 255.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product()` to combine the number groups in a single loop:

```
from itertools import product

ips = ('192.168.{}.{}'.format(*pair) for pair in product((42, 43), range(256)))
for ip in ips:
    print(ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use range(a,b), then it should be range(42,44) instead of 43.